# C# multiple SQL server selection

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, select, datagridview

I want to connect to a SQL server and select data from multiple tables using the SQL statements in the image below. SQL connection information is stored in the table. Finally, I want to show all the data from the `datagridview`.

[image]

Comment: What is your question ? And could you please post some code.

Comment: please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

You can't run sql queries on different servers in same connection. You can create a loop; for each iteration you will change connection string, execute query and load result to datatable.

```
List<string> lstSQLConStr = new List<string>();
lstSQLConStr.Add(@"Server=myServerAddress1;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;");
lstSQLConStr.Add(@"Server=myServerAddress2;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;");
lstSQLConStr.Add(@"Server=myServerAddress3;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;");
lstSQLConStr.Add(@"Server=myServerAddress4;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;");

string cmd = "SELECT * FROM BOOKS1 UNION SELECT * FROM BOOKS2 UNION SELECT * FROM BOOKS3";

SqlConnection sqlCon = null;
SqlCommand sqlCmd = null;

DataTable dtResult = new DataTable();

for (int i = 0; i < lstSQLConStr.Count; i++)
{
    using (sqlCon = new SqlConnection(lstSQLConStr[i]))
    {
        sqlCon.Open();

        using (sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(cmd, sqlCon))
        {
            sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            using (SqlDataReader dataReader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                dtResult.Load(dataReader);
            }
        }
    }
}

//here dtResult contains all results.
```

Comment: There are 368 units to be connected to sql server: (manual can not: (

Comment: You must have those 368 units stored in some list or something. loop through that table, can use a cursor to loop through that, and make dynamic queries to achieve

Comment: 368 different servers! Can't you use a loop? but it will be very bad design and may be very bad performance. 368 different connections will open, run query and close, pass the next one...

Comment: Furkan Bey 300 den fazla sql sunucusuna bağlanıp yapmam gerekiyor bu işlemi :(

Comment: Firstly we have to write English. You can create a loop; for each iteration you will change connection string, execute query and load result to datatable. I changed my answer, check please.

Comment: @user2416205 and if you want to use stackoverflow quality in Turkish like me please commit this [**post**](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/34945/stack-overflow-in-turkish)

Answer (score 0):

You can use linked servers. using linked servers, you can access different server databases from one query by following the format

```
     select <server>.<database>.<schema>.<table>
```

Also you can go for OPENROWSet approach where you can specify the server name, username password and write your sql query there.